# Are there any sources of mathematicians talking about their research methods?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, education

I recall reading [this article](https://philosophynow.org/issues/94/I_Re-Read_Therefore_I_Understand) that was written to explain how Descartes read philosophy effectively. I am wondering if such analogous tips have been made by past mathematicians?

Comment: One of the most famous self-reports is [Poincaré's Mathematical Creation](http://vigeland.caltech.edu/ist4/lectures/Poincare%20Reflections.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematicians rarely describe the process which led them to their discoveries.
One notable exception was Euler.
Some books on the subject written by great mathematicians are:

J. Hadamard, The Mathematician's Mind.
The Psychology of Invention in the Mathematical Field (English translation).

G. Polya, a) Mathematics and plausible reasoning. b) Mathematical discovery.

Comment: Wasn't it Newton who said something like "After the house is built I remove the scaffolding".

Comment: @NickR Gauss wrote something similar to that.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Gauss, was it.  I could not quite recall.  It was much grander than a house.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Cédric Villani's *Birth of a Theorem* does exactly that. A great read for scientists, even non-mathematicians.

Edit: The English title of the book is *Birth of a Theorem* and not *Living Theorem* (the French title is *Théorème Vivant*). Thanks to Torsten for pointing it out.

Comment: I assume you mean the book which is published in English translation as *Birth of a Theorem*, https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/23257776-birth-of-a-theorem.

Comment: Indeed I do, my bad ! I translated the French title literally. I do stand by my recommendation, though.

Comment: I second that. I recommended that same book in the related question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4033541/96384 on math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 4):

The first mathematician who did that was Archimedes, in his [*The Method of Mechanical Theorems*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Method_of_Mechanical_Theorems) (usually known as *The Method*).

Answer (score 2):

[Alexander Grothendieck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck), without a doubt one of the most creative mathematicians in the last 100 years, wrote a voluminous manuscript *Récoltes et Semailles* about (among other things) his approach to mathematics. Since he later requested that it be withdrawn from the public, it is hard (but probably not impossible) to find the full text on the internet.

One little snippet of this which has gained some popularity among mathematicians is the ["Rising Sea" metaphor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/The+Rising+Sea). There is an [article](http://www.landsburg.com/grothendieck/mclarty1.pdf) by [Colin McLarty](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/38/colin-mclarty) which discusses this, quoting at length translated passages from *Récoltes et Semailles*.

Comment: Ah yes, I've heard of Récoltes.
Part 1 in english [here](https://bbs.pku.edu.cn/attach/c1/e6/c1e6ee97b512106e/RS.pdf) (whole thing incomplete): ... Also french transcription in full [here](https://www.quarante-deux.org/archives/klein/prefaces/Romans_1965-1969/Recoltes_et_semailles.pdf)